# merge cells vba excel

Tags: excel, vba, merge, cell, rows

please my freinds I wanna merge cells in the last column

I used this code to find the last column

```
lastColumn = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

and this to find numbre of rows

```
nbrows = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
```

Comment: Try recording a macro, then look at the code it generates.

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution

```
Worksheets("sheet1").Activate
Range(Cells(1, lastColumn), Cells(nbrows, lastColumn)).MergeCells = True
```